# execute a line from a script in the current shell environment

Tags: shell, zsh

I'd like to execute a range of lines from a shell script from a running shell and using the current shell's environment.

For example, in a script that sets a variable to something I don't want to type (say an API key or MAC address):

```
line
   1 #!/bin/zsh
   2
   3 # Set the MAC address:
   4 MAC="12-34-56-78-90-ab-cd"
 ...
```

...and in my shell, I'd like to grab line 4 above, run it, and have $MAC exist in that environment

I've tried `sed -n '4p' script.zsh | zsh` but that doesn't affect the current shell I'm working in:

```
$ MAC="this is not a MAC address"
$ sed -n '4p' script.zsh | zsh
$ echo $MAC
---
this is not a MAC address
```

I could just copy and paste, but I'd like a solution I can use without touching my mouse - or when I don't have a mouse available.

Comment: Your question is pretty unique to `zsh` and `bash` might not be needed

Comment: @Inian, from what I know about `zsh`, it's supposed to use the same script syntax as `bash`, so I figured I'd get more attention with both tags.

Comment: @rreagan3 bash and zsh are really different in syntax and semantics; they just share a few common constructs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could combine your `sed` command with a process substitution and source it:

```
source <(sed -n '4p' script.zsh)
```

though you might want to use a pattern match for the  print line in case the line numbers shift.

```
source <(sed -n '/^MAC=/p' script.zsh)
```

Comment: that's not working for me - it still doesn't change the variable that exists in my shell environment. Good call with the `'/^MAC=/p'` pattern though, that's definitely more robust.

Comment: @rreagan3 Hmm, well, that's what the `source` command is supposed to do, and it does have update my current environment when I try it.  Do you get any errors or anything like that?

Comment: Nevermind, it works. I tried your solution on my work computer, where it didn't work, then went back to my personal laptop, where I was actually trying to implement the script, and it worked just fine. I'm not even gonna bother to figure this out on my work laptop - I'm leaving at the end of the week.